# Enable to refresh token on a java feign client

Tags: java, token, feign

I am trying to use a request interceptor to refresh a token on a feign client.
The problem is that the interceptor is executed on the first request and its not executed on other. Her's the code of the interceptor. I am using the common instant to try to refresh the token when its expired but the code is only executed on the first request. What is the good way to do that?

```
public AdeptClientConfiguration(TokenService tokenService) {
    this.tokenService = tokenService;
  }


  @Lazy
  @Bean
  @Qualifier("AdeptRequestInterceptor")
  public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor() {
    Instant instant = Instant.now();
    if (token == null || (instant.getEpochSecond()>token.getRefreshExpiresIn())) {
      token = tokenService.getAdeptAccessToken();
      token.setRefreshExpiresIn(instant.getEpochSecond() + token.getExpiresIn());
    }
    return requestTemplate -> requestTemplate.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.getAccessToken());
  }
```

This is how I inject the interceptor.

```
@Lazy
@FeignClient(value = "adept",  configuration = AdeptClientConfiguration.class, url = "${application.web.adeptUrl}")
public interface AdeptClient {
```

the method token.getAccessToken()) is returning me a new token.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor() {
        return requestTemplate -> requestTemplate.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + getAccessToken());
    }

    private String getAccessToken() {
        Instant instant = Instant.now();
        if (token == null || (instant.getEpochSecond()>token.getRefreshExpiresIn())) {
            token = tokenService.getAdeptAccessToken();
            token.setRefreshExpiresIn(instant.getEpochSecond() + token.getExpiresIn());
        }
        return token.getAccessToken();
    }
```